# Command window when executing a project with sqlite amalgamation

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I try to use SQLite with c/c++ for Windows programming :
- Code::Blocks
- GCC 4.7.1 (I can upgrade if necessary)

I downloaded the amalgamation version and put it in my project.
The project contains only a simple windowed application with an sqlite3_open command in the WM_CREATE message.

Build worked fine but the execution of the release output does nothing. The execution of the debug output gives a command window with the following text :

```
SQLite version 3.8.11 2015-07-02 18:16:02
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite>
```

I tried to delete the sqlite3 instruction in my code, but it seems the the only presence of the sqlite files in my project is the cause.

How can I do to override that ?

Thank you !!

EDIT : My code (the concerned parts) :
include file "appli.h" :

```
#ifdef MAIN_CPP
#define EXTERN
#else
#define EXTERN EXTERN
#endif // MAIN_CPP

EXTERN sqlite3 *DBase;
```

main.cpp :

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include "appli.h"
....
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow)

...
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;

        case WM_CREATE:
            if(sqlite3_open("DBase.sqlite3", &DBase) != SQLITE_OK) {
                MessageBox(hwnd,"Erreur d'ouverture de la base SQLite !!", "CDThèque", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE,0,0);
            }
            break;
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That output is from the `sqlite3` command-line shell (`shell.c`), which is *not* part of the amalgamation (`sqlite3.c`).

You must tell Code::Blocks that your program is a Windows application (starts at `WinMain()` and not a console application (starts at `main()`).

Comment: Too strong, CL !!!
I delete "shell.c" from my project and it works now fine.
Thanx a lot !

Comment: Thank you! You don't know how much you helped me! I have been having the same headache of OP for a few hours until I reached your post! Thank you!